# Twitter4j v3 for Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I am developing a twitter client twitter 4j to the library and I have several questions I could not resolve.

1) I need to know if a tweet has been retweeted by me. The method getRetweetedToMe() doent exist, How I can solve it?

2) I need to destroy a retweeted it has made earlier. The method twitter.destroyStatus(Long.parseLong(tweetId)); no working.  How I can solve it?

3) I need to know every tweet that belong to a conversation. This code does not work in version 3 of  twitter4j

```
            RelatedResults results = twitter.getRelatedResults(Long.parseLong(tweetId));
    List<Status> conversations = results.getTweetsWithConversation();
    /////////
    Status originalStatus = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong(tweetId));
    if (conversations.isEmpty()) {
        conversations = results.getTweetsWithReply();
    }

    if (conversations.isEmpty()) {
        conversations = new ArrayList<Status>();
        Status status = originalStatus;
        while (status.getInReplyToStatusId() > 0) {
            status = twitter.showStatus(status.getInReplyToStatusId());
            conversations.add(status);
        }
    }
    // show the current message in the conversation, if there's such
    if (!conversations.isEmpty()) {
        conversations.add(originalStatus);
    }
```

thank you very much!!